# How do I set up React-spring in codepen? how to

Tags: react-spring

```
import * as reactSpring from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-spring@9.2.6";
const { useSpring, animated, config } = ReactSpring;
```

I tried importing react-spring on codepen with this but it says  ReactSpring is not defined  any tips on how to setup react-spring on codepen

Comment: anyone wanna help?

Comment: I think to get more help you need to provide an actual example. At the moment it's hard to actually help